# Change the slug of a particular page every x hours

Tags: functions, pages

Is it possible to rewrite the slug of a particular page (e.g. Page-ID 123) with a wordpress function?

I found this somewhere but It doesnt work and I am also looking to simplify it as I just want to change the permalink of a single page

```
function rudr_post_permalink( $url, $post ){
    if( !is_object( $post ) )
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        
    $replace = $post->post_name;
        
    /* We should use a post ID to make a replacement. It is required if you use urf-8 characters in your URLs */
        
    if( $post->ID == 1 ) 
        $replace = 'hello-planet';
    if( $post->ID == 12 ) 
        $replace = 'Contacts';
        
    $url = str_replace($post->post_name, $replace, $url );
    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
add_filter( 'page_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rudr_post_permalink', 'edit_files', 2 );
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to change the slug of a particular page every x hours. I do not want to redirect the old slug to the new slug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a two step process for that.

1. Create a function that actually changes the slug (not rewrite it)
2. Schedule an event in WordPress to run that function in every X hours.

Here are something to start with

```
function wpse402903_schedule_event() {

    add_action( 'wpse402903_cron', 'wpse402903_cron_callback' );
    
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled('wpse402903_cron') ) {
        //Change 12 to your interval
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS, 'wpse402903_cron' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse402903_schedule_event' );

function wpse402903_cron_callback() {
    
    $post_id = 123; //The ID of the Post
    
    $postID = wp_insert_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => 'your-new-slug', //always use sanitize_title() if this generates dynamically.
    ));
}
```

The only drawback is the WP Cron. It acivates only if someone visits your site. For a site with regular traffic, this is not a problem though.

Comment: Just to add to @Abhik answer, you can create a REST Endpoint that instead of WP Cron and use your Server's Cron scheduler which will trigger it automatically without need for site visitors.

Comment: Please make sure to also check for that slug availability first, or you might run into issues. You could also use [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/)

Comment: yes I will be using a random slug each time so I need to incorporate that to the answer as well

Comment: hello, I am going to need this to work every 10 minutes without relying on site visitors... any help would be much appreciated - a random unique url slug should be created every 10 minutes

Comment: @JoaMika You can create a php file in your theme/plugin with the `wpse402903_cron_callback` function in the answer and include the `wp-load.php` at top of that file to use your custom function to be recognized by WordPress. After that, use your server's cron system to to call that file every 10 minutes.

Comment: thank you Abhik - very helpful answer !